# Detecting if mobile/desktop then changing the URL query string

Tags: javascript

I know there are ways to detect if the user is on mobile or desktop. But, is it possible to update the URL query string without reloading or redirecting to show the device type? i.e. www.mysite.com/?device=mobile

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Use [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "Mobile", "?device=mobile");
```

Note how ever that you are "pushing" the navigation. Meaning when you click the back button, it will go back to the non `?devive=mobile` url first before going back to the previous. So instead you can use `.replaceState()`